# java.io.IOException: unknown format

Tags: java, socket.io, gzip, gzipinputstream, socket.io-java-client

I use the code below to decompress coming data that is arrived via `socket.io`.

When decompressing data which has been sent as compressed the code below works great. (Pseudo data which is sent from Node.js: `<Buffer a8 b2 ...>`)

However when decompressing data which has been sent in a JSONArray I get `java.io.IOException: unknown format` error. (Pseudo data which is sent from Node.js: `[<Buffer a8 b2 ..>, <Buffer c4 f0 ..>]`)

```
mSocket.on("fired", new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        JSONArray compressedDataArray = (JSONArray) args[0];
        byte[] compressedData = compressedDataArray.getString(0).toString().getBytes();
        String unzipped = new String(decompress(compressedData));
        Log.v("SAMPLE_TAG", "unzipped: " + unzipped) // LOGGING THE RESULT
    }
})


public byte[] decompress(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPInputStream gzipIS = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int len;
    while ((len = gzipIS.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      byteArrayOS.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    byteArrayOS.close();
    gzipIS.close();

    return byteArrayOS.toByteArray();
  }
```

Is there any chance to overcome this issue?

Comment: What's the reason for decompressing an uncompressed JSONArray?

Comment: I've store data as compressed on Redis. In some cases I have to return more than one compressed data to the user. Because of this, I add the compressed data into an array then send.

Comment: Another remark `compressedDataArray.getString(0).toString()` the last `toString()` seems to be redundant. `getString(index)` already returns a `String`

Comment: You have a JSON Array which contains compressed data. 1) I don't see that you iterate over the JSON Array. 2) Independent of you have one or n compressed elements, send them as JSON Array which contains n elements of compressed data  so you can treat them equally.

Comment: Thanks but this is not important in this case. Thanks anyway..

Comment: I've just written an example. `byte[] compressedData = compressedDataArray.getString(0).getBytes();` and `String unzipped = new String(decompress(compressedData));` lines enough to reproduce the exception. That's the reason. 2) Why not if I can decompression. Thank you again..

Comment: You can't decompress an uncompressed array even when the elements are compress. You can only decompress compressed elements. One after another. Use always the same structure / abstraction for your data so you can easily handle them. A possible abstraction is always to use an array of compressed elements independent of number of elements.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. You spent your time with me about this issue. I've added an answer which works. Have a fabulous day..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've overcome this issue by changing the line below:

```
byte[] compressedData = compressedDataArray.getString(0).toString().getBytes();
```

changed as:

```
byte[] compressedData = (byte[]) compressedDataArray.get(0);
```

Then it works.

Comment: It's the call .toString() that makes the first statement fail. Just remove it and it should work just fine.